# What is the restriction on flat catalog if my store has more than 500K SKUs?

Tags: category, flat

I have a customer with more than 5 million products and 2500 attributes. They are using
an external system to push products to specific ecommerce sites. They would like to push 500,000
product to their Magento and these products include 900 attributes. 200 of which are text fields.
In additional to enabling flat catalog, which solution can to meet their requirement?

A. Convert the text field attributes to dropdowns or combine to description
fields

B. Use Magento websites w aired traffic to specific stores

C. Ask the client to only use 250,000 SKUs along with new attribute sets

D. Convert attributes types to use a custom extension

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the exact column limit is because it depends on certain factors. However, since Magento 2.3 and higher, using Flat Catalog is no longer a best practice and this is confirmed by Magento.

Please visit the dev docs. https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/catalog/catalog-flat.html

The solution to your problem is to not use Flat Catalog tables.

Comment: If you still need to pick one answer among A-D, which one you think is more make sense?

Comment: To be honest, parts of the question are a little unclear to me. But to talk it through, I don't see how new attribute sets would solve anything. In fact, they'd probably degrade performance due to the catalog size and the creation of brand new EAV relationships increases that kind of load. Also, a text field cannot be converted to a "dropdown" as offerered in option A. Text is a type of field. Drop down is an input which likely uses a varchar field. Option D is not understandable. Not sure about option B either